# How to make PhpStorm realize JavaScript injection in argument passed to a method

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

I pass JavaScript to a method in a class and want PhpStorm to realize the injection (and style it and so on). I tried this but it does not work:

```
MyClass::myMethod ("
myJavaScriptFunction (myVar);
//language=JavaScript
");
```

Comment: Try `/** @lang javascript */`

Comment: @Magnus Do what @TobiasF. said -- add such comment **just before** the string with your JS code (e.g. `MyClass::myMethod (/** @lang javascript */"`). You may also do what @Deckerz suggesting .. but that might be a temp injection -- it should not be adding any comment so may disappear after you end your editing session (IDE/project restart).

Comment: @TobiasF and @LazyOne brought me on the right way. Solution is to insert `/* language=JavaScript */` **just before** the String – e.g. `MyClass::myMethod (/* language=JavaScript */ "…")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to insert /* language=JavaScript */ just before the String – e.g.

```
MyClass::myMethod (/* language=JavaScript */ "
myJavaScriptFunction (myVar);
");
```

Thanks to @TobiasF and @LazyOne who brought me on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [wiki](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Language+Injections+%28mix-ins%29+in+PhpStorm#LanguageInjections(mix-ins)inPhpStorm-1.2.ManuallyInjectingaLanguageReference) you press `alt+enter` and select an intent for the language and it will highlight accordingly